# Javascript Audio solution

Tags: javascript, html5, audio, browser-based-games

still has issues. Flash works but... requires flash (an issue for iOS). What do you use in Javascript for audio?

Comment: SoundManager 2 is BSD licensed. http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2
How well has it worked for you, (or did you go with something else)?

Answer (score 4):

I tried HTML5 audio on [my first game](http://www.momentumracer.com) but I could not get it to work perfectly (lag for the first time the sample is played etc).

SoundManager2 looks ok and I tried it a bit in a [demo](http://www.momentumracer.com/electricanvas). For the next game I will use it as it has functionality to fall back to HTML5 audio in case Flash is not available.

Comment: Was the audio clip still loading when you first tried playing it?

Comment: I used preload="auto" and actually it worked better on FF than on Chrome.

Answer (score 4):

From what I gather, HTML 5's audio potential has a long long way to go. Firefox 4 Beta apparently has a [cool audio API](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API) but it's going to be a little while before we see the major browsers provdie comprehensive support for the [W3C Web Audio API Standard](http://chromium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/audio/specification/specification.html)

Answer (score 2):

As of recent Google Chrome updates (13.0.782.32) the HTML5 audio tag has been working perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2):

Both Webkit (specifically chrome) and Firefox have come a long way since this question was asked:

http://chromium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/audio/index.html

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API#Working_Audio_Data_Demos

Google's recent recreation of the moog synth using webkit's audio context API made me decide to finally try to build something for webkit. They used a flash fallback for other browsers, and I may do that or I may just wait until the browsers standardize an API for audio and then adapt to whatever that is. The real question is: how soon does this need to be ready? For me, it's experimental and for fun and resume building, so I don't care if I don't have a shippable product for a year or so. But if you need it to work on all browsers NOW, flash is the safest bet.  See this article regarding the IE dev team and why they had to use flash audio for Cut the Rope:

http://creativejs.com/2012/01/why-cut-the-rope-uses-flash/